# Взаимодействие между формами

Tags: c#, winforms

есть главная форма, из нее открываются все остальные.
одна из них должна задавать например цвет всем другим формам.
я знаю что это можно сделать через "owner" и прописывать в каждой форме функцию смены бекколора этой формы и вызова ее из формы меняющей цвет.
Но я думаю что должно же быть более удобное решение 
на пример сделать первую форму владельцем всех остальных и как то обращаться ко всем дочерним 
или записать все формы в массив. 
что бы это занимало не куча строк в виде функций и вызова их, а что то более адекватное.
и собственно вопрос возможно ли это , если да то как ?

Comment: Много что можно придумать, например 1) Глобальная шина сообщений 2) Выделенный сервис для предоставления цвета формам 3) Поиск всех открытых форм вручную 4) и тд

Comment: [Application.OpenForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?